# How to delete tt_content elements which do not have any connection to a page

Tags: typo3

I want to find all tt_content elements from a TYPO3 installation, which do not have a connection to a page. How would you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `tt_content` record has connection to the page via `pid` field, the only reason for opposite situation is manipulating with `tt_content` records manually (i.e. creating them by some external script or even adding to DB with phpMyAdmin).

For permanent deleting contents from pages that was deleted via TYPO3's backend (and also any other types of records), you can just use `Recycler` extension - it's system one, so just go to Extension Manager and enable it. Then select the highest page in your tree, choose depth *Infinite*, and you'll find all soft-deleted records by type, deleting them in the Recycler will remove them totally from DB.

If for some reason you have such situation that `pages` record with given uid doesn't exists at all, although tt_content uses its pid, the Recycler won't find it. These can be only found by SQL query:

```
SELECT tt_content.uid, tt_content.pid, pages.uid page_uid 
FROM tt_content  LEFT JOIN pages  ON (tt_content.pid=pages.uid)
WHERE pages.uid IS NULL
```

**Disclaimer:** Manual DB manipulation should be avoided as long as possible. TYPO3's backend is able to maintain deleted records very well and first try built-in tools. I do not response for any damages caused by manual DB changes, for your own safety make a DB backup before deleting/modifying ANY records.

Comment: Hey biesior. I manipulate the pages and tt_content tables using a import/export script. There is no other way I can think about. 
Your query is just what I needed. Thanks.